# Necessity of TypeAlias in Python

Tags: python, class, alias, typing

I am trying to understand in which cases `TypeAlias` is necessary in Python. Consider the following code:

```py
class Internal:

  def f(self):
    print("Hello!")


class Container:
  internal = Internal

RenamedInternal = Internal
ContainerInternal = Container.internal

def f1() -> Internal:
  obj = Internal()
  obj.f()
  return obj

def f2() -> RenamedInternal:
  obj = RenamedInternal()
  obj.f()
  return obj

def f3() -> ContainerInternal:
  obj = ContainerInternal()
  obj.f()
  return obj


f1()
f2()
f3()
```

`mypy` reports

```
example.py:24: error: Variable "example2.ContainerInternal" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
example.py:24: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
```

That can be fixed by

```py
class Container:
  internal: TypeAlias = Internal
```

It is not clear to me why it is necessary for `ContainerInternal` but not for `RenamedInternal`. Also does adding type alias has a functional effect?

Comment: Did you read the link? https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases

It pretty clearly states that implicit type aliases are only allowed at the top level of a module (probably for backwards compatibility), but if you want to use it in a class definition or function, it explicitly states "You should always use `TypeAlias` to define a type alias in a class body or inside a function."

Comment: Note, the recommendation is to *always* use `TypeAlias` when defining a type alias.